# How to enable back button in a screen after using Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() to replace the page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Let's say I have two screens A and B .

I am on screen A and I use pushReplacementNamed() to get to screen B.

Now I want to go back to screen A when user swipes right (default in iOS for back button).

Screen A :

```
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/B'),
```

Screen B :

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/A');
        return false;
      }),
```

But this is not working. Back button is still disabled.

Note - I don't want to make custom back button in AppBar to achieve this. I want to use the default back button behaviour.

Comment: First, swiping right (from the edge) is only available on iOS devices not Android by default. Second, if you use pushReplacement, the `Navigator` replaces the existing route from the stack, so you can't go back like that.

Comment: I am not using the existing routes. I know they are Null. I am providing what should happen on willScope . I am confused why is the willScope code not working.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is wrong with your code is that you're returning false from onWillPop, return false disregards the action of the back tap. Try changing that to true.

Also if you want to eventually go back to screen A from screen B it makes more sense to just use a push() on screen A and then on screen B inside onWillPop you no longer need to manually pop the route using navigator, you can just return true.

### Update

In response to the your comment below, for what you want to achieve, you can normally **push** a route when on `Home` page and then on other pages you could just use `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil("B",ModalRoute.withName('Home'));
```

It will push the page you want and remove everything until page Home. Since "Home" will now always be the root, you no longer need to override `onWillPop` and can proceed with a normal pop on back button.

***Note***: Page "Home" has to already be present in the stack for this to work.

---

If you want to push and remove **everything** else from the stack change:

```
 ModelRoute.withName("Home"),
```

To

```
(Route<dynamic> route) => false,
```

Comment: Changing it to true is not working. I have actually multiple screens in the drawer that's why I am using replacement method. I want all of the drawer screens to go back to home page which is not in the drawer on back press.